# Does anybody else experience micro-freezes with the Raspberry over wifi?

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, camera, streaming-video

whenever I connect my Raspberry Pi over wifi to the LAN, I sometimes get micro-freezes when streaming video from the Raspberry or when I connect over ssh. It seems kinda periodic. The freeze/lag has a duration of ca. 1 second and after that everything goes back to normal.

Is it a problem with the Pi or maybe with the router?

What do you think?

Comment: if its Raspbian then make sure the kernel and firmware are up to date http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

Comment: Switch wireless power management off (man iwconfig, power option).  I didn't get micro-freezes, but I did get freezes of about 30 seconds before I discovered this option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a different wifi adapter? When I bought my Pi, I bought a kit that came with an adapter that gave me nothing but trouble. As soon as I replaced it with a different one, everything worked fine.